# use of strchr() giving error

Tags: c++, strchr

I am trying to find the occurrence of characters of one string(s1) in other string(s2).

This is part of my code.

```
for(;i<strlen(s1);i++)
{
   int x=strchr(s2,s1[i]);
   if(x>0)
   count++;
}
```

But on compiling I get an error pointing to strchr() and says

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
```

Anyone explain what is problem in using strchr() function.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't read its documentation. I'm wondering why would you **ever** try using a function when you **know** you have no idea what it is doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment is wrong strchr doesn't returns int but returns address of first char in string found:

```
int x=strchr(s2,s1[i]);
```

should be:

```
char* x = strchr(s2, s1[i]); 
//         ^ returns char*
```

Read manual

> [`char *strchr(const char *s, int c);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)
>
> RETURN VALUE
>   The `strchr()` and `strrchr()` functions
>   return a pointer to the matched    character or `NULL` if the character
>   is not found.  The terminating    null byte is considered part of the
>   string, so that if c is specified    as `'\0'`, these functions return a
>   pointer to the terminator.

And so:

```
if(x>0)
```

should be:

```
if(x != NULL)
```

or just `if(x)`

Comment: how to return position of character in string??

Comment: @user3160274  if you wants to use `strchr()` then you can use pointer difference  `ptrdiff_t index = x - s2`  Although  you should use `ptrdiff_t`

Comment: @user3160274 check this working C code @[codepad](http://codepad.org/zwBe3LA5)

Comment: Is there any faster function that can be used to get the position of character in a string?

Comment: @user3160274 I don't have any idea but you can write your own: `int indexof(char* str, char c){ int index = 0; while(*str &&  *str != c) index++; return index;}`

Comment: are you sure its correct?? function doesn't return anything.. you should increment character pointer.

Comment: @user3160274 No indexof() I commented  is not correct as I forgot to `str++`   the codrrect code is @[codepad](http://codepad.org/7b9iMAiB)